# como hacer show.() a mas de una class a la vez

Tags: jquery, class, show

Hola estoy intentando hacer lo siguiente:

```
       $('.1','.btn').show();
```

quiero hacer visible solo los div's que tienen esas dos clases juntas asi:

```
        <div class="1 btn">
```

he probado haciéndolo así:

```
           <div class="1.btn"> 
           $('.1.btn').show();
```

y tampoco funciona:

Comment: Con Jquery con una coma entre selectores actúa como `OR` , `$('.btn,.1)` _(clase btn o clase 1)_ , y sin la coma y sin espacios como `AND` , `$('.btn.1')` _(clase btn y clase 1)_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En realidad es una mezcla de tus soluciones. Las clases debes indicarlas en el atributo html separadas por espacios:

```
<div class="1 btn">
```

Y en el selector jQuery precedidas por un punto para indicar que hace referencia a una clase y sin separar:

```
$('.1.btn').show();
```

```js
$(function(){
  $('#ocultar').click(function(){
    $('.1.btn').hide();
  });
  $('#mostrar').click(function(){
    $('.1.btn').show();
  });
});
```

```css
div, button{
  padding: 10px;
}

div{
  border: 1px solid #666666;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="1 btn">
  Div 1 btn
</div>

<div class="btn">
  Div btn
</div>

<div class="1">
  Div 1
</div>

<button id="ocultar">Ocultar</button>
<button id="mostrar">Mostrar</button>
```

Comment: Gracias ahora probaré

Comment: gracias me ha funcionado!!!